# How to prove something preserves structure?

Tags: functions

An isomorphism, by definition, is something that preserves the structure of whatever type of object we are talking about. For example, an isomorphism between two groups $G_1(X,+)$ and $G_2(Y,*)$ is a function $h$ with the property that $h(a+b)=h(a)*h(b),\ \forall a,b\in X$, but how can one prove that this function preserves structure, i.e. has same structural properties? More generally, how can one know if an arbitrary transformation on a given mathematical object preserves its structure, say, a function $f$ with the property that $f(x)+f(y)=f(x)^{f(y)}$, where $+$ and $\text{^}$ are given operators on given structure?

Comment: The structure is given, so you just check it.

Comment: @Randall How? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Randall What I meant is how you can prove that all properties regarding the structure are conserved after the isomorphic transformation?